# Use of is and was

Tags: verbs, tenses

Which one is correct?

As I told you before, my manager is pregnant and is due in two months.

or

As I told you before, my manager was pregnant and was due in two months.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a proofreading service, though if you can [edit your post](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/272500/edit) to identify a specific question concerning grammar or usage, we may be able to assist. What is the context of the sentence? What leads you to believe one or the other may be incorrect? What references have you consulted? I strongly encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

> "As I told you before, my manager is pregnant and is due in two months."

Assuming it is now true that the manager is pregnant and is due in two months, since this is the main clause, there is no reason to shift it to past tense.  If this clause were subordinated to "told", however, then tense could be shifted to past, even though the situation continues to hold true in the present:

> "I told you before that my manager was pregnant and was due in two months."